# The leatest research regarding ergodic operators

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory, reference-works

I always ask myself the following question which states:

Where might the leatest research regarding ergodic operators be found ?

It is undoubtedly I am not asking for the books that illustrate the classical idea about ergodic operators such as U.krengel Ergodic theorem or Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory since I have already had both of them.

I want something new and books containing open problems.

Comment: I don't know but when you find out, let me know!  Thanks!